# Cannot access axios.all in vue component

Tags: vue.js, axios

I initialize my `axios` instance in one file and attempt to use it in another but I cannot seem to get `all` working:

```
// axios.js
import axios from 'axios'

const baseURL = "http://api.lvh.me:3000/api";
const token = '';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  headers: { 'authentication': token }
});
```

I then use this instance in my components:

```
// component
import axios from "../axios"

export default {
    data() {
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null
    },
    created() {
        const g_sheet = axios.get(`/dashboards/google_sheets.json?&start_date=${ this.startDate }&end_date=${ this.endDate }`)
        const leads   = axios.get(`/dashboards/potential_clients/simple?&start_date=${ this.startDate }&end_date=${ this.endDate }`)
        axios.all([g_sheet, leads]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
            const g_response    = responses[0]
            const lead_response = responses[1]

            console.log(g_response, lead_response)
        })).catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors)
        })
    }
```

Calls like `get` have been working, but `all` has not.  I see the error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: _axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.all is not a function
```

Comment: What is `others.all`?

Comment: my apologies, typo.  It should have been `axios` instead of `others`

Comment: `axios.all` and `axios.spread` are supposed to be [deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042) for `Promise.all` and ES2015 destructuring. You should switch to those instead.